# Remove new lines from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, regex

Consider I have the following string:

```
{
  "{\n <<<-- error
     \"SomeKey\": {\n    \"somevalue\": \"test\",\n,
     \"AnotherKey\": \"Long string should be here \n another line break here \n and another line here \"
    }
}
```

When you try to parse this string with JSON.parse, it throws an error that points to the first line break. Is there any way to get rid of the line breaks without removing \n that is not within quotation marks.

Comment: What generates this json string? That's the point you should address, not trying to fix broken json later on.

Comment: So basically it returns a formatted JSON response, that contains \n in the beginning of every line.

Comment: share you actual JSON.

Comment: What is that endpoint? It's not generating proper json.

Comment: How do you parse the XML then?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 15):

Strip `\n` from the JSON string and do `JSON.parse`

```js
var json_data = "{\n \"Fullname\": \"Alex Johnson\",\n \"FirstName\": \"Alex\", \n \"LastName\": \"Johnson\"\n }";
 
 var obj = JSON.parse(json_data.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ''));
 
 console.log(obj);
```

Comment: That will work, but it will be applied to the content within the quotation marks as well.

Comment: I think the real fix is, you should request proper JSON from Backend or API team.

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.stringify` and remove the line break;

```
var json = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
json = json.replace(/\\n/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array or a map and turn it into proper JSON string because that JSON string looks like it's made by faulty string concanetation logic